# An Example of the firebase FIRUser.sendEmailVerificationWithCompletion(FIRUser) function swift IOS

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/FirebaseAuth/3.0.2/Classes/FIRUser.html#//api/name/sendEmailVerificationWithCompletion:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/ios/firebaseauth/interface_f_i_r_user#method-detail

Could anyone give me an example on how to use this function?
I would appreciate any help regarding what to type inside the parentheses.
The links explain a bit about this function.

Comment: Hey @marc, let me know if you still have any other concern. If no could you please set my answer to accepted? thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see in the documentation the callback is **optional**. It is a function that will be called as soon as the email verification finish. So you should use this parameter to call any logic that you want after the verification is completed.

On the following example the verification is called in an IBAction and when finished it tests if any error occurred.

```
@IBAction func didRequestVerifyEmail(sender: AnyObject) {
     FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.sendEmailVerificationWithCompletion({ (error) in
          if let error = error {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
            return
          }
          print("Sent")
     })
}
```